# kendoui multiselect single tag mode max selections can't unselect

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik

when I use the kendoui multiselect in single tag mode with a maxselection, if I hit max selections I can't deselect items.  is there a work around for this?

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect

I updated this snippet

```
http://dojo.telerik.com/ovAsA
```

to this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
    <option>Item1</option>
    <option>Item2</option>
    <option>Item3</option>
    <option>Item4</option>
</select>
<script>
$("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
  tagMode: "single",
    maxSelectedItems: 3 //only three or less items could be selected
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and once I select 3 items I can't deselect items.

Comment: it works normal  , i am still able to deselect items

Answer (score 1):

After 2 hours , here is what you want [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/40wmmkf2/1/)

```
var maxSelectedItems = 3 ;

$("#multiselecta").kendoMultiSelect(
{
  tagMode: "single",
  maxSelectedItems: maxSelectedItems
});
var multiselect = $("#multiselecta").data("kendoMultiSelect");

$("#multiselecta").parent().find(".k-multiselect-wrap.k-floatwrap").on("click",function(e)
{
    if(multiselect.dataItems().length >= maxSelectedItems)
    {

      $("#multiselecta_listbox li").on("click",function()
      {
        if(multiselect.dataItems().length >= maxSelectedItems)
        {
          var index = $(this).attr("data-offset-index");
          var currentVal = multiselect.listView._view[index].item.value;

          if($(this).hasClass("k-state-selected"))
          {
            var indexArray = multiselect.listView._values.indexOf(currentVal);
            if (indexArray > -1) 
            {
                multiselect.listView._values.splice(indexArray,1);
            }
          }

          multiselect.close();
          multiselect.refresh();
        }
      });


      $(".k-animation-container").css(
      {
        "display":"block",
        "overflow":"visible"
      }).find("#multiselecta-list").css(
      {
        "display":"block",
        "transform": "translateY(0px)"
      });
    }
});
```